# Firefox CSSCoverage Tool - Save Used CSS

Tags: html, css, firefox

I've just found the [CSSCoverage tool](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/CSS_Coverage) in the firefox dev. edition.

It shows the unused CSS classes from a page / set of pages that can supposedly be safely removed to slim down your stylesheets.

My question is, does anyone know a way to save the stylesheets from the console **without** the unused rules. It visibly displays them so surely there's a way? When I click save, it saves the original (full) stylesheet.

Comment: If I run `csscoverage report`, it gives me all the unused rules... But it's still a manual job to remove them?

Answer (score 0):

There is way to copy the classes which you add run time through inspect element in browser by clicking on one of newly added class, then it shows you only new one.

But I think there is no way to select only those classes which are useful to grab all other classes

Thanks